# Sequelize (PostgresSQL) many to many chat implementation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been trying to create a chat app with Node JS and Sequelize. Now i'm stuck at a problem of creating a query to find a conversation that has my id and user's id(the one i'm trying to text). So the thing i'm trying to do is send a post request with and id of a user i'm sending a message to, then i look through my Conversation model and check if that conversation has my id and id of the user i'm texting to.

My models are associated through Many to Many relationship. So the main objective is to find a conversation with **only** my ID and ID of the user i'm texting to with the **same** ConversationId.

Here are my models:
User

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    {}
  );


    User.belongsToMany(models.Conversation, {
      as: "conversations",
      foreignKey: "user_id",
      through: models.ConversationUsers,
    });
    User.hasMany(models.Message, {
      as: "messages",
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

Conversation

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Conversation = sequelize.define(
    "Conversation",
    {
      lastMessage: DataTypes.STRING,
      recipients: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER),
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Conversation",
    }
  );

  Conversation.associate = (models) => {
    Conversation.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      as: "participants",
      foreignKey: "conversation_id",
      through: models.ConversationUsers,
    });
    Conversation.hasMany(models.Message, {
      as: "messages",
    });
  };

  return Conversation;
};
```

ConversationUsers Many to Many through model

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ConversationUsers = sequelize.define(
    "ConversationUsers",
    {
      user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      conversation_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "ConversationUsers",
    }
  );

  return ConversationUsers;
};
```

Message

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Message = sequelize.define(
    "Message",
    {
      conversationId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
      sentTo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      sentFrom: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      body: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Message",
    }
  );

  Message.associate = (models) => {
    Message.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "messageTo",
      foreignKey: "sentTo",
    });
    Message.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: "messageFrom",
      foreignKey: "sentFrom",
    });
    Message.belongsTo(models.Conversation, {
      as: "messages",
    });
  };
  return Message;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can remove some pieces from your models and rework it a bit.
Messages don't need a `sentTo`, they only need a `sentFrom`. You can use the `ConversationUsers` table to know who the recipients are. This also gives you the flexibility to have Conversations with more than 2 members, because your current model essentially enforces that a Message can only be to one user.

So let's walk through the models first with changes

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    {
    // I think moving the associations to other files might make this more clear
    }

  );
  };
  return User;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Conversation = sequelize.define(
    "Conversation",
    {
        // perhaps something like a subject could go here e.g.
        subject: DataTypes.STRING(500),
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Conversation",
    }
  );

  Conversation.associate = (models) => {
    Conversation.hasMany(models.Message, {
      as: "ConversationMessages",
    }); // adds ConversationId onto Message, gives us Conversation.getConversationMessages() etc
    models.Message.belongsTo(Conversation); // create association both ways for convenience methods to find convo from a message 
    models.Message.hasOne(Conversation, {
        as: 'LastMessage', 
        constraints: false, 
        allowNull:true, 
        defaultValue:null
    }); // adds LastMessageId onto Conversation model (you'll have to write code to maintain this value, probably through an afterCreate hook on Message model)

  };

  return Conversation;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Message = sequelize.define(
    "Message",
    {
     id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true, // if you want to do the hook thing i talked about to set LastMessageId, you need to put this in 
    },
      body: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Message",
    }
  );

  Message.associate = (models) => {
     Message.belongsTo(models.User, {as: "sentFromUser"});
  };
  return Message;
};
```

```
   // I'm going to rename your many-to-many table "ConversationMembers"
   module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   const ConversationMembers = sequelize.define(
    "ConversationMembers",
    {
    // again, the associations will build these fields for you
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "ConversationMembers",
    }
    );

    models.Conversation.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: "ConversationMember",
      as: "Members",
    }); // gives us Conversation.getMembers()
    models.User.belongsToMany(models.Conversation, {
      through: "ConversationMember",
      as: "MemberConversations",
    }); // gives us User.getMemberConversations()
    ConversationMember.belongsTo(models.Message, { as: "LastReadMessage" }); // gives us the potential ability to track the last read message for each convo member as ConversationMember.LastReadMessageId, you'll need to set this value manually on read for each user if you care about having it
    models.Conversation.hasMany(ConversationMember);
    models.User.hasMany(ConversationMember);
  
    return ConversationMember;
```

Okay now onto your question, which perhaps becomes simpler at this point. If you already know the `ConversationId`, all you need to do is check that the person who is sending the message is a member of the conversation. Then if they are, write a row into the `Messages` table. It doesn't matter who the message is "to"--you're writing to the members of the Conversation, not to any individual.

```
async function canMessageHelper({conversationId, userId }) {
    const convo = await models.Conversation.findOne({
        attributes: ["id"], // whatever attrs you need, probably not many if any
        where: {
            id: conversationId,
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.ConversationMember,
            attributes: ["ConversationId"], // whatever you need if anything
            where: { // this where is critical, it creates an inner join so convo only returns if myUserId is a member of the Conversation
                 UserId: userId 
            }
        }]
    });
    
    if (!convo) {
       return false;
    }
    return convo;

}

async function sendMessage({conversationId, authorUserId, messageText}) {
   const allowMessage = await canMessageHelper({conversationId, userId: authorUserId}); 
   if (!allowMessage) {
      return false; 
   }
   await models.Message.create({sentFromUserId: authorUserId, body: messageText});
}
```

If you want to try this, be sure you remove any tables you've already created with these names from your database before you sync.

I have not provided any code for the hooks I mentioned, but you will have the groundwork to develop those ideas out.

Comment: Hi, what if i actually only want the message to be sent to only 1 user?

Comment: You can still use this, just have some logic to ensure each Conversation has at most 2 members.